# How to use NSBrowserDelegate on 10.5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsbrowser

I have a question: When I was running the sample code [SimpleCocoaBrowser](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimpleCocoaBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html&ei=oY03TuynNc-CsgKQsdUd&usg=AFQjCNHTB-RE89upKTPm7_Hu_4THUckmHw), I received a crash report about the `NSBrowserDelegate`, which I discovered can only be used after 10.6. So how can I use an `NSBrowser` in 10.5? Just use the `NSBrowser` without `NSBrowserDelegate`?

by the way, my english is bad...

thx

Comment: Can you post the specific crash report you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what kind of crash you have experienced, but `NSBrowser` has always (since 10.0) had a delegate. It is just that the `NSBrowserDelegate` became a formal protocol in OS X 10.6.

If you don't want to use the `NSBrowserDelegate` explicitly, you can just not declare your delegate to conform to it, and it should still work.